# Changing the default RSS reader of Google Chrome

Tags: rss, google-chrome, rss-reader

Where can I properly change the default RSS reader setting of Google Chrome? I didn't find it in the settings.

When I click "subscribe", it subscribes me to Winamp. I really wonder how that happened! (Fairly new Windows installation.)

Actually I installed Google Chrome 12 just yesterday, while my settings etc. are admittedly synced to the Google servers. Also I'd like to subscribe to another desktop feed reader, just in Chrome you can only add "web" URLs both in the official and in unofficial extensions.

I tried to add this (all one line but formatted here to prevent scrolling)

```
javascript:var url=decodeURIComponent('%s');var feedWindow = 
window.open('feed://' + url.substr(7)); feedWindow.close();
```

as it was described as solving the problem in some blog, but actually sadly it didn't. Basically it's ridiculous that I can't set the RSS reader in Google Chrome itself, even using the developer version!

Comment: Is this relative to Chrome or the OS? What happens when you try to subscribe to the same RSS feed from IE (I suppose you're on windows given Winamp) or Firefox without touching any of their defaults settings?